# How to annotate horizontal Seaborn countplots?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, seaborn

How do I manipulate the location for the annotations so that they are displayed at the end of the bars?

This is what I've got so far : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhNmS.png

And, here's the code :

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(15,10))
ax = sns.countplot(y="carrier", hue='Delay_Level', data=Subset_Data)
plt.xlabel('count', fontsize=15, weight = 'bold', labelpad=10)
plt.ylabel('ABC', fontsize=15, weight = 'bold', labelpad=10)

for p in ax.patches:
    x=p.get_bbox().get_points()[:,1]
    y=p.get_bbox().get_points()[1,0]
    ax.annotate(y,(p.get_height()+2,p.get_y()+0.15))
```

Would appreciate it if anyone could help me out. I'm a beginner. I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE :**

I've found the solution :

```
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(int(p.get_width()),((p.get_x() + p.get_width()), p.get_y()), xytext=(1, -18),fontsize=9,color='#004d00',textcoords='offset points', horizontalalignment='right')
```

Instead of using the points of the bounding boxes, I've used the get_width to get the width of the rectangles. "textcoords" helped in placing the annotations next to their respective bars; it indicates the type of coordinates used in xytext. Setting the "horizontalalignment" to "right" gets them towards the end of the bars. Also added in "fontsize" and "color" for the annotations.

Comment: Could I ask what is `((p.get_x() + p.get_width())`, please?